# Xamarin - Visual Studio not showing my device, which is showing in Android Device Monitor

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I am trying to debug my application on my phone. I looked around and tried to replace drivers and so on but still can't get my device to show in the run menu.
The weird thing is that I see my device when I click on Tools->Android->Android Device Monitor and it looks to be online. I can capture the screen of my phone and all but still can't debug anything on it.

The odd thing is that I can see my device when typing in cmd `adb devices` but VS2015 will not show my device.

BTW the device is a Nexus 6p

Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: If you use `adb devices` on a command prompt, what does it list your device as?

Comment: @JonDouglas It listed as a device

Comment: Problem solved. it seems that for some reason I had several installation of the Android SDK and while I was pointing VS to one of them I was updating the other...

Comment: Please add an answer to your own question and mark it resolve.